# How to get the list of objects from Json using Java and Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I try to read from a Json file and convet it to Java object, I have the following Java code to read the Json:

```
class Item {
    String name;
    int itemId;
    Date AddTime;
    String group;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(jsonFile, new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<Item>>>() {}.getType());
```

And the Json file contains the following data:

```
{
  "item1": [{
    "name": "test1",
    "itemId": "1",
    "AddTime": "2018-09-05T10:35:56.015Z",
    "group": "computer"
  }, {
    "name": "test2",
    "itemId": "2",
    "AddTime": "2018-09-05T10:35:56.016Z",
    "group": "computer"
  }, {
    "name": "test3",
    "itemId": "3",
    "AddTime": "2018-09-05T10:35:56.017Z",
    "group": "computer"
  }],
  "item2": [{
    "name": "test4",
    "itemId": "4",
    "AddTime": "2018-09-05T10:35:56.015Z",
    "group": "computer"
  }, {
    "name": "test5",
    "itemId": "5",
    "AddTime": "2018-09-05T10:35:56.016Z",
    "group": "computer"
  }, {
    "name": "test6",
    "itemId": "6",
    "AddTime": "2018-09-05T10:35:56.017Z",
    "group": "computer"
  }]
}
```

I got the following:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1
```

I am new to Java, what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like your file doesn't really start with `{`. You might want to check it for invisible chars (maybe an UTF-8 BOM?)

Comment: @Aaron Sorry I do not know what you mean

Comment: The error is complaining that the first character GSON encounters isn't a `{`, yet the file you posted visibly starts with a `{`. You should check that you're actually reading the file you think you do, but aside from that there might be invisible characters at the start of the file that would explain the error. You could check for their presence using an hex editor or a text editor with a "show all/control characters" function

Comment: `but was STRING at line 1`, means you have a quotation character at the very beginning of the JSON text, not a `{` character

Comment: Also `int itemId; Date AddTime;` fields might not work... Every field in the JSON is only text, and you've not given a date parser to Gson

Comment: I tried your example with gson version 2.8.5. There is nothing wrong with it. I am able to parse the json without any problems / errors. As @Aaron mentioned, there could be an invisible character at the beginning from your file.

Comment: @kAliert I check the Json file, there is no invisable char, still get the same error

Comment: Can you try to copy & paste your json example you posted here, save it as a json file and parse it again? (thats what i did and i got no error). BTW: which gson version do you use?

Comment: I try it again, it is fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but I think the solution could be something like this.

According with your dataset. Inside of each one of your items you have an arrayList with tests (test1, test2...) so you will need something like this:

```
    class Item {
       ArrayList<Test> tests;
    }

    class Test{
       String name;
       int itemId;
       Date AddTime;
       String group;
    }
```

Comment: I tried the example from @ratzip (gson version 2.8.5). There is nothing wrong with the given example, so i don´t think he has to change anything.